# AWS SSM to patch on-prem servers?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssm, aws-ssm, amazon-systems-manager

I am trying to patch on-prem servers using aws SSM. When I use 'run command' I am specifying a tag to limit patching to a set of servers.
Unfortunately, this isn't listing targetted servers basing on tag selection. Is there any other alternative? I am trying to avoid accidental selection of the wrong tag. If we can see filtered servers at the bottom that would be awesome.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are running AWS-ApplyPatchBaseline document you need to use patch groups if you want to use tags for applying patches. Here is the link to the documentation - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/sysman-patch-patchgroups.html